# Send email without intent

Tags: firebase, email, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, firebase-extensions

I'm asking if there's a method to send an email automatically from my app in Android Studio without opening Gmail with "Intent.ACTION_SEND" and without turning on "less secure apps" on Google account settings. My app has already a Google sign-in method connected with Firebase Project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to Firebase and sending emails to users, the best option that you have is to use [Trigger Email Extension from Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firebase-firestore-send-email). There is no need to open your Gmail account in order to send an email. To implement the extension please follow the steps that are explained in the following article:

- [How to install and use Trigger Email Extension from Firebase?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-install-and-use-trigger-email-extension-from-firebase-f6f9763c8088)

Comment: but it is not free to use

Answer (score 2):

### Is it possible

---

Yes, it is possible. There are decades of libraries for this on the web.You should have tried surfing for a while.

### How to Implement

---

You should use [this](https://github.com/1902shubh/SendMail) library.Code is given below

```
SendMail mail = new SendMail("youremail@email.com", "yourEmailsPass",
    "otherUser'sEmail@email.com",
    "Title",
    "Yes, it's working well\nI will use it always.:)");
mail.execute();
```

### References

---

1. [Github](https://github.com/1902shubh/SendMail)
2. [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CpSDz67nWMw)

Comment: I checked the video, but I saw that you must turn on "less secure apps". So I hope there's a different way to do this.

Comment: then i am sorry to say but you cannot do it without less secure apps.but you surely can send the mail